# How to hide admin parts of angular site

Tags: angularjs, authentication

I want to hide the admin part of my site if you are not in the admin role.
This means that while not logged in, the routing for the admin should return a 404 as not existing, and the view templates should not be served. Once logged in the routing table should be updated and templates should become available.

I think that the server part of not serving the pages could be done if using something like MVC for serving the templates, but I don't know if it is possible to have no references to the admin in angular till you are logged in?

So somehow angular needs to refresh its template for the menu, and routing table.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/whisher/lama the nitty-gritty https://github.com/whisher/lama/blob/master/public/system/services/interceptor.js and https://github.com/whisher/lama/blob/master/public/users/routes/users.js

Comment: what are you using for routing, ng-route/ui-router/mvc routing??